# Incremental indexing using logstash handle delete scenario

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash

I am using below Logstash configuration for doing incremental indexing in this whenever a new row inserted or updated I am able to get those particular rows from MSSQL server and insert it as a document in elasticsearch but the challenge is with delete operation.

**Logstash configuration file**

```
input {
jdbc {
jdbc_driver_library => ""
jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxx;databaseName=xxxx;"
jdbc_user => "xxxx"
jdbc_paging_enabled => true
tracking_column => modified_date
tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
use_column_value => true
jdbc_password => "xxxx"
clean_run => true
schedule => "*/1 * * * *"
statement => "Select * from [dbo].[xxxx] where modified_date >:sql_last_value"
}
}

filter {
 mutate {
   remove_field => ["@version","@timestamp"]
 }
}

output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => "xxxxx"
user => "xxxxx"
password => "xxxxx"
index => "xxxxx"
document_type => "_doc"
document_id => "%{id}"

}
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

How to delete the documents which get deleted in MSSQL server with incremental indexing approach using Logstash. I am not having any idea how to handle particularly the delete operation.

Could anyone please suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: Could you mark as "to delete" the rows need to be deleted on MSSLQ? In this case you could delete those documents on elastic because you know the ID to delete

Comment: Is it possible to do Insert and Delete simultaneously using same config file

Comment: If i use action => "delete" all the documents in elasticsearch deleted so is it possible to do both insert and delete operation using same config file or else should i have to maintain different configuration file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi All i am able to handle Insert,Update and Delete using the below code. This may be helpful to some one who is trying the same

```
input {
jdbc {
jdbc_driver_library => ""
jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://xxxxx:1433;databaseName=xxxxx;"
jdbc_user => "xxxxx"
jdbc_paging_enabled => true
tracking_column => modified_date
tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
use_column_value => true
jdbc_password => "xxxxx"
clean_run => true
schedule => "*/1 * * * *"
statement => "Select * from [dbo].[xxxx] where modified_date >:sql_last_value"
}
}

filter {
if [is_deleted] {
        mutate {    
            add_field => {
                "[@metadata][elasticsearch_action]" => "delete"
            }
        }
        mutate {
            remove_field => [ "is_deleted","@version","@timestamp" ]
        }
    } else {
        mutate {    
            add_field => {
                "[@metadata][elasticsearch_action]" => "index"
            }
        }
        mutate {
            remove_field => [ "is_deleted","@version","@timestamp" ]
        }
    } 
}

output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => "xxxxx"
user => "elastic"
password => "xxxxx"
index => "xxxxx"
action => "%{[@metadata][elasticsearch_action]}"
document_type => "_doc"
document_id => "%{id}"

}
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

Thanks to all particularly Claudio M

Comment: if [is_deleted]: What would this field be? is a field of your statement?

[@metadata][elasticsearch_action]: and this field belongs to elasticsearch itself or is it something from your statement?