# how can insert, update, delete automatically in elastic using logstash

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, logstash-configuration

how can insert, update, delete automatically in elastic using logstash?

In my input statement I get the action (insert, update, delete), it works fine when I only do insert, or only update, but if the process runs with insert and update or delete it throws error code => 400,% c => "http: // ip: 9200 / _bulk action =>

```
output{
# Para ELK
        elasticsearch {
                    hosts => "localhost:9200"
                    index => "hca_001"
                    document_type => "hca_001_lgs"
                    document_id => "%{hca_numero}%{hca_anio}"
                    action => "%{my_accion}"   
                    doc_as_upsert => true
                    manage_template => false        
        }
}
```

Comment: I have tried this and it worked: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59854441/incremental-indexing-using-logstash-handle-delete-scenario

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to work with conditionals?

```
output{
  if [my_accion] == "delete" {
        elasticsearch {
                    action => "delete"   
                    ...  
        }
  } else {
        elasticsearch {
                    action => "update"
                    doc_as_upsert => true   
                    ...  
        }
  }
}
```

This has solved similar problems for me in the past.

Comment: I have tried and it was throwing error in the .conf file.
I'm going to try again, maybe it was some key that I forgot.

:) Thanks.